# extern const with typedef struct

Tags: c, extern

I have in .h file:

```
typedef struct MyName {

uint8_t AA;
uint8_t BB; 
};

extern const MyName NewName[num];
```

in file .c I have:

```
const MyName NewName[num] = {{0x01,0x02}, {0x03,0x04}};
```

Compiler complains 'unknown type name' MyName. How I can get around this? Thank you for helping.

Comment: yeah.. my general impression is that typedef means synonymous with .. so in this instance you're not specifying what the structure is synonymous with (or to)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct way to write this is:

in the .h file

```
struct MyName 
{
   uint8_t AA;
   uint8_t BB; 
};

extern const struct MyName NewName[];
extern const int num;
```

in the .c  file it should be:

```
const struct MyName NewName[] = {{0x01,0x02}, {0x03,0x04}};
const int num = sizeof( NewName ) / sizeof(struct MyName);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `typedef` should be

```
typedef struct myName 
{
    uint8_t AA;
    uint8_t BB; 
} 
MyName;
```

Without the final `MyName`, you haven't actually `typedef'd` anything.

Comment: I was about to say this.. though I haven't done C enough to determine whether I was correct....

however, what about: typedef struct _MyName {} const MyName ??

Comment: Must admit that I've never included a `const` in the `typedef` itself, but you certainly could. The reason I wouldn't is because there may be cases where I need an instance of the struct that isn't `const`.

Comment: The original code is actually illegal, although some common compilers seem to accept it without comment (and apparently just ignore the `typedef` keyword)

Comment: Since that format of defining a struct is depreciated, and full of other problems, such as the use of the typedef.  Much better to loose the 'typedef' text and then everywhere the struct is mentioned, use struct _MyName.  BTW: using a leading underscore is very bad practice as it can conflict with the names that compiler produces.

Comment: `_MyName` is a reserved identifier; do not use it.